# Is there an ubuntu command that identifies password encryption types?

Tags: command-line, password, encryption

I need to know if there's a command or a software that tells me what password encryption type a password is. I know that I can identify it myself but I'm a beginner and I don't have time for that. Please help!

Comment: No. You can't simply determine the encryption type by looking at the encrypted password, though you can guess. We aren't here to help with homework. You can try the [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Comment: What format is the password? Same as `/etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are interested in the password associated with a user account on the system.

Look into `/etc/shadow` at the entry corresponding to the user in whom you are interested. The password string begins with `$`id`$`, where *id* is the identifier of the password encryption method. The encryption methods are documented in `man 3 crypt`.

Here is a small Bash function which looks up the password encryption type of a user account:

```
passwd_encryption_method()
{
  crypt_id="$(
    sudo grep "$1:\\$" /etc/shadow |
    sed 's/^[^:]*:$\([^$]*\)$.*/\1/'
  )"
  if test -z "$crypt_id"; then
    echo Cannot find user "$1", or "$1" has no password
    return 1
  fi
  case "$crypt_id" in
    (1) echo MD5;;
    (2a) echo Blowfish;;
    (5) echo SHA-256;;
    (6) echo SHA-512;;
    (*) echo Unknown method, id="$crypt_id";;
  esac
}
```

Copy the function definition and paste it at the shell prompt; you can then call it as `passwd_encryption_method username`, replacing `username` with the name of the account in which you are interested.